# WhatsApp Forensic Analysis

Tags: android, forensics, whatsapp

I was wondering if anyone is aware of any conferences that cover WhatsApp security on android or something similar. My project requires me to look for three conference papers and justify why they are relevant, however I can't seem to find any. I have already looked through:

- search.proquest
- Science direct
- web of knowledge
- Google scholar

Comment: What has this got to do with forensics...?

Comment: @user2339071 so i'm Forensically Analysing whatsapp for artifacts that can be used court  in my project, and as result i have to find conference papers/presentations that have information related to either android application security or whatsapp

Comment: Why does it have to be "conference papers"? That's an odd requirement.

Comment: it's just what the marking scheme specified, but even then i then i think presentations are also allowed, as long as it was presented in a conference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help with your project.
**Network   and device forensic analysis of Android social-messaging applications:**
http://www.dfrws.org/2015/proceedings/presentations/DFRWS2015-p9.pdf

**Forensic Analysis of Instant Messenger Applications on Android Devices:**
http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1304/1304.4915.pdf

**"Learning Android Forensics" By Rohit Tamma, Donnie Tindall:**

Nice book with good forensics examples: Analysis of Skype,Snapchat,Viber,Tango,WhatsApp, Kik, WeChat

Comment: Thanks! i will use the first one as one of the examples, i don't think Mahajan's paper was presented at a conference though ? i'm looking for presentations/papers at conferences. However, I will be looking into the DFWRS conferences.